# Android Studio: Cannot open .txt file into EditText - keep getting Permission Denial error

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, txt

In my Android app `Song_Tracker` I wish to open `txt` files I have copied over from my laptop - files are stored in the `\Internal storage\DCIM\sheet_music` directory, when I parse the directory and load the file name I also load the file `URI`.  I wish to open the `txt` file into a EditText field so the user can either view or edit/save.  I have the `txt` file names stored within my SQLite db and, eventually wish to swipe from one song to the next, each loading in a RecycleView.

Here is the error I receive:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.enetapplications.songtracker/com.enetapplications.songtracker.editsong.NewEditSongActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: 
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{f235d79 11381:com.enetapplications.songtracker/u0a540} 
(pid=11381, uid=10540) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I have set permissions in the `Manifest` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

I have tried using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` however this opens a file picker which I do not want - I wish to simple click or swipe from one `txt` file to the next without needing to go to the file picker for each file.

Here is the `.class` that is opening the file incorporating tips from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).  The code seems to function properly but I cannot tell as I continually get the Permission Denial error.  I have tried to user `requestPermissionLauncher` in the code below but same error.  I have tried `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` still same error.

```
package com.enetapplications.songtracker.editsong;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.enetapplications.songtracker.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class NewEditSongActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 123; // Define your own request code

    EditText editTextSongContent;
    TextView textViewSongName;
    Uri songUri; // Storing URI to be accessible throughout the class

    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted, proceed to open the file
            openFile(songUri);
        } else {
            // Permission denied, handle this situation (e.g., show a message or adjust app behavior)
            // For instance: showToast("Permission denied. Cannot open the file.");
        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_edit_song);

        editTextSongContent = findViewById(R.id.editTextSongContent);
        textViewSongName = findViewById(R.id.textViewSongName);

        // Get the URI of the file to open
        String uriString = getIntent().getStringExtra("song_uri");
        if (uriString != null) {
            songUri = Uri.parse(uriString);

            // Check for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted, proceed to open the file
                openFile(songUri);
            } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Explain why your app requires this permission and what features are disabled if declined
                // An educational UI should be shown to the user
                // For instance: showInContextUI("Explanation for access to external storage");
            } else {
                // Request permission using the ActivityResultLauncher
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void openFile(Uri uri) {
        // Open the file and read its contents
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if ((line = reader.readLine()) == null) break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            editTextSongContent.append(line);
        }

        // Close the file
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 11.2.2023

---

Based upon **blackapps** comment:
Here is the flow of the code for `NewEditSongActivity.java`

1. User clicks on song from RecyclerView (previous screen) which Intent goes to `NewEditSongActivity` the parameter `song_uri` is passed
2. onCreate() (variables assigned, receive Intent for uri and stored in `uriString`)
3. check for `uriString` != null
4. check if the app has permission to read files from the external storage - which passes and processing continues
5. calling openFile() which processing goes to however after `InputStream inputStream = null;` is set the processing stops at the try/catch blocks

Based upon **Elnur's** comment.  I tried, just to see what happened using `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` - added this to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

...but received the same error:

```
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{8374b4e 31718:com.enetapplications.songtracker/u0a540} (pid=31718, uid=10540) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

One more thing I tried, just to see if I could get the code to work was re-build the app using `Android 5.0 - API level 21` and adjusted the `build.gradle` with:

```
minSdkVersion 21 //was at 29
```

I synced and rebuilt and ran the app but the SAME issue with `Permission Denial`.  This may shed some light but not to my eyes :)

Comment: `\Internal storage\DCIM\sheet_music` That is what you see on your pc. For your Android app on your Android fevice that would be \storage\emulated/0/DCIM\sheet_music.

Comment: `Here is the error I receive:` Well which statement exactly causes that message? And can you first explain what your code does? Step by step?

Comment: Thank you @blackapps for your input, I've edited my post to give more information about the processing flow

Comment: The files dont belong to your app so your app has no access unless it goes foe MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as was earlier suggested.

Comment: Better use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user select the directory with the files. Then list the files in the directory.

Comment: Appreciate the comment @blackapps!  I was able to get file picker working using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` - and the file opened in the EditText however the app needs to work by creating a song list, and simply swiping will open the next song, etc.  This is a music app where it is not possible to pick the file from the directory each time.

Comment: Please reread my comment. You once pick the directory with the files. You never pick a file.

Comment: OK - I see - I'm not familiar so will need to dig into this.  It looks like the user selects the directory once in the lifetime of the app and with permissions is always able to access without explicitly being prompted...thanks again - will look into this!

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave comments, so I'll leave it here
As far as I understand, you need control over all system files, if so, then try

```
 MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Please note that this is a high risk resolution.
and there is also official documentation about this on the Google console website
[site](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Elnur.  I added to my main statement, please review...